# Android Studio Multiple dex files define

Tags: java, android, gradle, build, android-multidex

I'm trying to build multidex project and get some error:

```
:app:compileDebugNdk NO-SOURCE
:app:compileDebugSources
:app:transformClassesWithRetrolambdaForDebug
:app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug
:app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error converting bytecode to dex:\nCause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout$OnPreDrawListener;","sources":[{}],"original":"UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:\ncom.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout$OnPreDrawListener;\n","tool":"Dex"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout$OnPreDrawListener;","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:661)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:616)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:598)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:198)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerCallable.call(DexArchiveMergerCallable.java:61)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerCallable.call(DexArchiveMergerCallable.java:36)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1424)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"\tat java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)","sources":[{}]}

 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout$OnPreDrawListener;
```

My **build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
        classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.6.1'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'


repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.1'
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1"
        multiDexEnabled true

        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            shrinkResources false
            minifyEnabled false
            debuggable false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            shrinkResources false
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt')
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://jitpack.io"
    }
    maven {
        url 'https://download.01.org/crosswalk/releases/crosswalk/android/maven2'
    }
    mavenCentral()
    google()
}



dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.8.0@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }

    compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.0'


    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'

    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'

    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'


    compile ('com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2')    

    compile ('com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.2') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support.design.widget'
    }

    compile ('com.evernote:android-job:1.1.11')    
    compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.4')    
    compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.0.4')    
    compile ('com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4')    
    compile ('com.neovisionaries:nv-websocket-client:2.3')    

    compile ('com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.6.0')    
    compile ('com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.6.0')    
    compile ('com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.6.0')    
    compile ('io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1')    
    compile ('io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.8')    
    compile ('com.artemzin.rxjava:proguard-rules:1.2.9.0')    
    compile ('com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.2.0')    
    compile ('com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.2.0')    
    compile ('com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.2.0')    
    compile ('io.requery:requery:1.4.0')    
    compile ('io.requery:requery-android:1.4.0')    

    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.3'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    annotationProcessor 'io.requery:requery-processor:1.3.0'

    compile 'org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library:19.49.514.5'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'
```

I'am trying to use

```
exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'design-v13'
exclude group: 'com.android.support.design'
exclude group: 'android.support.design'
```

It did not help. How can I exclude this library from all the compilers or somehow another way to solve this problem ?

And how to see which libraries the module is duplicated in ?

What is interesting - an hour ago it worked, the code did not change. Building is fine, the error crashes when I try to install the application on the emulator

Comment: Checkout this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49040605/4729523

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how, but it helped:

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a dependency issue. Please update the version of each dependency with auto-suggestion.