# Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout$LayoutParams

Tags: android, build.gradle, android-multidex

I'm getting Multiple dex files define error in my project.

I'm using these two tags in **build.gradle** as well

```
dexOptions {
    preDexLibraries = false
}
defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true

}
```

but still getting this error.

```
   Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout$LayoutParams;
Error:com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout$LayoutParams;
Error:  at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:661)
Error:  at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:616)
Error:  at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:598)
Error:  at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
Error:  at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:198)
Error:  at com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerCallable.call(DexArchiveMergerCallable.java:61)
Error:  at com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerCallable.call(DexArchiveMergerCallable.java:36)
Error:  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1424)
Error:  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
Error:  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
Error:  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
Error:  at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout$LayoutParams;
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Update the library versions to `27.1.0` solve the isssue for me.

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
```

To:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:27.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:27.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
```

Comment: I have changed 26.+ to 27.1.0 and issue fixed thanks

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: I did this, now I'm getting a different error
Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v13/view/DragAndDropPermissionsCompat;
This is frustrating

Answer (score 2):

in build.gradle file enable multidex and add the multidex library as a dependency,as shown:

```
android {
defaultConfig {
    ...
    minSdkVersion 15 
    targetSdkVersion 26
    multiDexEnabled true
}
...
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

By default on the new support library versions when you add `"multiDexEnabled = true"` , its dependency is being added automatically , but for some reason if you want to support older support versions you have to include the dependency manually for it to compile.

This will remove `Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v13/view/DragAndDropPermissionsCompat` error and other 16 errors along with it.

Consider the link : https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex
for detailed information.

Answer (score 0):

Updating the gradle plugin (*com.android.tools.build:gradle*) from 3.2.0 to 3.3.2 solved the issue for me.