# Error:com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout$HierarchyChangeListener

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, android-multidex, rx-binding

I have tried with these solutions - [Solution 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49073231/7166151) [, Solution 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49040605/7166151)

Here are my gradle dependencies.

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    //Recycleview
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.2'
    //Butterknife
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
    //SDP
    implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.5'
    //OkHttp
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.9.1'
    //RxJava and RxAndroid
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.6'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
    implementation 'io.ashdavies.rx:rx-firebase:1.3.3'
    //RxBinding
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding:rxbinding-design:0.4.0'
    //Retrofit
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.3.0'
    //Glide
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.6.1'
    //GSON
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    //Image Crop Library
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.6.+'
    //Dagger Android
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.13'
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.13'
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.13'
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.13'
    //Only applying android dagger.
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
}
```

I have doubt on 'RxBinding design' dependency due to Coordinate layout duplicate class may be exist, so I think I need to exclude `CoordinatorLayout$HierarchyChangeListener` but from which dependency not sure.

So I need your help thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add the following in your `build.gradle`

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
        force 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'
        force 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    }
}
```

For more information you might consider reading from [this link](https://www.devsbedevin.com/android-understanding-gradle-dependencies-and-resolving-conflicts/).

Comment: Thank you Reaz,Yes it's work for me. Now can you please guide me why we have written this lines and how it works ?

Comment: Its like forcing all other libraries to use the exact version that you are defining here. Please see the updated answer which has a link for understanding the resolution strategy. Glad to know I could help. Welcome.

Comment: Thanks again Reaz, I will tell you for guiding me if I will stuck in this things.

Comment: Sure thing. Please let me know.

Comment: @ReazMurshed Great Answer but i want add resolutionStrategy for aar file I mean I have to add it for crashlytics. so how should I add it ?